# Загрузка по URL (не локального) файла с помощью cURL

Tags: curl, php

Здравствуйте.

Нужно реализовать загрузку по URL (не локального файла) с помощью cURL.

Наработки:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file'=>"http://site.ru/image.jpg"));
```

Но этот код не работает.

Comment: Вам нужно скачать себе на компьютер удаленный файл или наоборот?

Comment: Наоборот - закачать на другой сервер. Т.е. есть сайт site.ru, на котором картинка, есть сайте skript.ru, на котором скрипт и есть сайт site1.ru, на который нужно закачать.

Comment: Насколько я помню, нужно указывать полный путь к файлу, у не url. Т.е. что-то типа

`
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file'=>'@'.dirname(__FILE__).'/image.jpg'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае нужно сначала закачать картинку на сайт skript.ru например так:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$file = fopen('image.jpg', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.ru/image.jpg');
curl_exec($ch);
```

А затем уже загружать на сайт site1.ru.

Или можно сделать так:

создать на сайте site1.ru скрипт, который будет ждать некие пост параметры(например 'file'=>'адрес картинки') и после получения адреса картинки будет скачивать её вышеописанным кусочком кода.

P.S

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file'=>"http://site.ru/image.jpg"));
```

Вы же здесь передаете адрес картинки а не саму картинку.

Comment: Суть данного вопроса была в том, что я хотел обойти эти 2 способа, но всё равно спасибо)